# Bitbucket pipelines doesn't triggered on feature branches

Tags: build, triggers, bitbucket, pipeline, bitbucket-pipelines

Hi guys I've this configs into my bitbucket-pipelines.yml

```
    pipelines:
  branches:
    '{master, develop, feature/branchThatDontTrigger}':
      - step:
          caches:
            - node
          script:......
```

Both for master and develop the pipeline works but since when I've added the feature branches it doesn't start. I've also try writing the name of the branch without the prefix `feature/` but nothing has changed.

Can someone help me? Shoul I change something into settings repository?

Answer (score 0):

I've been learning Bitbucket Pipelines the last 2 days and a thing that popped right out of your configuration is that you shouldn't have spaces between the branch names.

```
'{master, develop, feature/branchThatDontTrigger}'
```

should be

```
'{master,develop,feature/branchThatDontTrigger}'
```

Also if you want you can include all feature branches with `feature/*`.

Here's one example of that: [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48073799)